# Add a link to an ::after property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to replace the text of a div and add a link to it. Basically I don't have the ability to directly modify a text so what I'm doing is modify that text with the ::after property, and I would like to link the new 'copy' that I'm replacing so that it takes you to another page. Here's my code:

```
<div class="category-name">
    <span itemprop="productname" data-masterid="03324">Blue Male T-shirt</span>
</div>
```

and here's the CSS I'm using to change the text 'Blue Male T-shirt:

```
.category-name {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.category-name::after {
  content:'Electric Blue Tee'; 
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  border: none !important;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Now, I've found a script to add to make the after property a link, but I can't seem to be able to make it work:

```
<script>
jQuery('.category-name::after').each(function() {
  var link = $(this).html();
  jQuery(this).contents().wrap('<a href="example.com/script.php?id="></a>');
});
</script>
```

Does anybody know what I'm putting wrong? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: 'Basically I don't have the ability to directly modify a text', why don't you?

Comment: @Manav Because I can't access the server now, but I can add code in a different platform that will make changes in the site

Answer (score 0):

You cannot wrap pseudo-elements in HTML tags. The most you can do is wrap the `span` element inside the `.category-name` element in the `a` tag.

```
jQuery('.category-name > span').each(function() {
  jQuery(this).wrap('<a href="example.com/script.php?id="></a>');
});
```